# Find substring between angle brackets using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following string :

```
abc <abc@gmail.com>, def <def@gmail.com>
```

I want to get value only between <>.
The output should like :

```
abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com
```

How can i do this using jQuery?

Comment: Can you *only* use jQuery, because there are plenty of ways to do this with javascript?

Comment: I can use both jQuery and javascript but what is the solution

Comment: Comments aren't used for answers (solution) that's why I made a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is not required for this.

You could use the regular expression `/\<(.*?)\>/g` to capture the characters between the brackets.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gp5wc9ww/)

```
var matches = [];
'abc <abc@gmail.com>, def <def@gmail.com>'.replace(/\<(.*?)\>/g, function(_, match){
  matches.push(match);
});

console.log(matches.join(','));
```

Output:

```
"abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com"
```

Comment: This did not work. I am getting <abc@gmail.com>,<def@gmail.com>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
'abc <abc@gmail.com>, def <def@gmail.com>'.replace(/.*?<([^>]+)>/g,",$1").substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by `,` and then find the position of `<` and `>` and then do a substring

```
$(function(){

  var s="abc <abc@gmail.com>, def <def23@gmail.com>";
  var sa= s.split(',');
  $.each(sa,function(i,item){      

    var start=item.indexOf("<");
    var end=item.indexOf(">");

    var email= item.substring(start+1,end);
    console.log(email);

  });

});
```

Sample jsBin [here](http://jsbin.com/tepinaxida/edit?html,js,console,output)